Jupyter notebook file not getting saved
The jupyter notebook file gets saved for the code written in the first few minutes only. Any code written after that does not get saved and gives me this error everytime. I have tried restarting Kernel, uninstalling and reinstalling Python and Jupyter notebook but the problem still remains.

tried restarting Kernel, uninstalling and reinstalling Python and Jupyter notebook but the problem still remains.

check the permission of the folder that you are trying to write to
